# Is it possible to do Docker-compose pull from Gitlab CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have images in my `docker-compose.yml` file that I would like to pull when my CI Runner is executing the build.

Everytime I try I run into this:

```
Pulling web (registry.gitlab.com/xxxxx/xxxxx/crm:latest)...
Pulling repository registry.gitlab.com/xxxxx/xxxxx/crm
Error: image xxxxx/xxxxx/crm:latest not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to login to the registry first

`- docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" $CI_REGISTRY`

Answer (score 1):

To build on @llya-kuchaev answer the related gitlab docs are here: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/23/gitlab-container-registry/

Your version of gitlab might change the environment variables you need to use.  In version 9+ use $CI_JOB_TOKEN in earlier versions use $CI_BUILD_TOKEN, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/ for all the changes that were made in v9 (there were loads)